# Passing A JSON Object To An ASP.NET MVC Controller Method Using A Key Value Argument

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, json

I'm wondering if it's possible to pass JSON data into an ASP.NET MVC controller method that uses a KeyValuePair type as an argument. I have a breakpoint on the stopper variable in the controller method. When I debug, I have the following values for x and y:

x = 0

y = null

How can I get the keyValuePair variable to populate correctly from the JSON object?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function () {
    $.ajax({
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        dataType: 'json',
        type: 'POST',
        url: '@Url.Action("KeyValuePairTest", "Home")',
        data: JSON.stringify({
            keyValuePair: {
                Key: 1,
                Value: 'some text'
            }
        })
    });  
 });
</script>


using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace MvcApplication1.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }

        public void KeyValuePairTest(KeyValuePair<int, string> keyValuePair)
        {
            var x = keyValuePair.Key;
            var y = keyValuePair.Value;
            var stopper = "stop";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You should deserialize the KeyValuePair to get a value. You can use Json.Net http://james.newtonking.com/projects/json-net.aspx to do so

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use custom a model binder. When you use a custom model binder, you will have access to the form collection, where you will be able read the raw data posted to the controller action. Once you have the data, you can map it to any data structure, including a key value pair. Please have a look at the following post

[Persisting data back to ViewModel with a dynamic .aspx page ASP.NET MVC 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14841976/persisting-data-back-to-viewmodel-with-a-dynamic-aspx-page-asp-net-mvc-3/14843889#14843889)