# Map Json to Dictionary

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, json

I am trying to map Json to Dictionary. Earlier I had Dictionary with key of type 'long' . But after realizing for mapping to happen key needs to be of type 'string or 'object'.

Now my type definition in c# is like this :

```
public class StyleItemCreateCommand
{
    public long StyleId { get; set; }
    public Dictionary<String, string> SelectedItemToColorMap { get; set; }
}
```

And json which I am generating is like this:

```
{"StyleId":"1710","SelectedItemToColorMap":{"1391":"583","21531":"7733"}}
```

But still somehow it is not being mapped. I am using asp.net mvc controllers as a service, which is being consumed by jquery client.

MVC method signature is as following:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create(StyleItemCreateCommand command)
    {
    }
```

The dictionary object is always null. Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: How are you deserializing your JSON?

Comment: It is done by ASP.Net MVC architecture implicitly. No explicit code for that.

Comment: Your JSON for `SelectedItemToColorMap` is an object. I think it should be an array of objects as in `{"StyleId":"1710","SelectedItemToColorMap":[{"1391":"583"},{"21531":"7733"}]}`

Comment: I can still change my C# class to have an object instead of dictionary. But still I wanted to understand why this is not being mapped. And what all need to be done to make this happen? Also using dictionary is the most suitable option as it provides me ease of access to values.

Comment: what is your version of ASP. net mvc ??

Comment: using ASP.Net mvc 4.0

Answer (score 0):

I think the reason why this is happening is that

```
"SelectedItemToColorMap":{"1391":"583","21531":"7733"}
```

is an object and your StyleItemCreateCommand
class defines a Dictionary. Change the class property to:

```
public object SelectedItemToColorMap { get; set; }
```

and you should be able to see the values. You can then redesign your class/es. 
Alternatively amend the json by surrounding the { } with [ ] converts SelectedItemToColorMap to an array of key value items.

**UPDATE**
Just tried in asp.net mvc 4 with a simple view

```
<input type="button" value="click1" id="click1" />
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
<script>
    $(function () {

        //this is called by a Get action on the controller
        $('#click1').click(function (e) {
            var jsonObject = { "StyleId": "1710", "SelectedItemToColorMap": { "1391": "583", "21531": "7733" } };
            $.ajax({
                url: "@Url.Action("Create")",
                type: "POST",
                data: JSON.stringify(jsonObject),
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                error: function (response) {
                    //process error;
                },
                success: function (response) { 
                    //process success; 
                }
            });

        });

    });
</script>
```

The above appears in the body of the view. And the controller is

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create(StyleItemCreateCommand command)
    {
        if (command != null) {
            string value1 = command.SelectedItemToColorMap["1391"];
            string value2 = command.SelectedItemToColorMap["21531"];
            Debug.Assert(value1 == "583" && value2 == "7733");
        }
        return View();

    }
```

Which uses your StyleItemCreateCommand - and it all works. Ok the above uses JSON.stringify(jsonObject) so **what format is your json object** that is actually coming from the post request? It would be interesting to see the request body (eg using chrome developer tools under the network section).

.Net serialization (not being used here) will wrap requests in a .d object as a security measure against auto execution of code, could this be what is happening?

Comment: I used some similar approach to get it to work. I used list of objects on the server side, and from jquery I passed array. Still I wont accept this as a answer, as still it is not clear what will be the json to map to C# Dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

Now after searching around web I found out that ASP.Net MVC is not gonna do it implicitly. Found this answer :
[https://stackoverflow.com/a/15220050/756722]